# Find angle between two lines by given equations

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, affine-geometry

I have equations: $3x + y - 2 = 0$ and $4x - 2y + 5 = 0$. My target is to find angle.

I have used formula: $\tan\theta= \frac{m2-m1}{1 + |m2||m1|}$

First I convert equations:

$y = -3x - 2$ and

$-2y = -4x + 5$ **=>**

$-y = 2x + \frac{5}{2}$ **=>**

$y = -2x - \frac{5}{2}$

Now I got: $\tan\theta= \frac{-2-3}{1+-2.(3)}$, which will result of $\frac{-5}{-5}$, which in angles is 57.29°, but the right answer is: $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Where is my mistake. Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy..You have almost solved it .
You have already shown $\tan(\theta)= -5/-5= 1$
All that remains is to find a special value of theta to satisfy the equation..
taking $\arctan$ on both sides...One finds the answer to be $\pi/4$...
$$\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$$
$$\tan(\pi/4)=1.$$

Comment: Imagine that I do not know the answer. How can I get it?

Comment: Which is the formula that I get from $\frac{-5}{-5}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: Its generally hard to find value of $\theta$ for many angles without a calculator..but you can easily find values of $\theta$ for some basic angles( like multiples of 15).

Comment: You are not answering my question at all

Comment: Think it this way....Which value of $\theta$ when evaluated with a tangent function gives 1 ?....I can only think of one which remains in the arctan's domain.....that is between -90 to 90

Comment: Please don't answer me with questions. Either explain either delete your comment

Comment: Could you please clarify what are you not getting?

Comment: Read my second comment

Comment: There is no formula for it...You just have to find the value satisfying the equation (either using a calculator or by your own if you remember tan($\theta$) of special angles) ...DO you get it now?

Comment: From calculator $\tan\theta$ is 57.29°, and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is 45°

Comment: Have you studied about inverse functions of trigonometric functions?

Comment: No, I have ask a straight question. I am not professor and stop post comments that did not target to answer my question

Comment: Think like this tan($\theta$)=1=tan($\pi$/4)  .. SO $\theta$ equals $\pi$/4

Comment: Why not tan(θ)=1=tan(π/14)? Why $\theta$ should be equals to $\pi/4$?

Comment: Why $\pi/4$ why not $\pi/10$ or any number? Why 4?

Comment: Because tan($\pi^2$/4) is -0.799.. which is not equal to 1

Comment: because only tan($\pi$/4)=1...No other value of $\theta$ gives 1

Comment: 57.29° is more close to 60°, not to 45°.

Comment: so why not $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Search on google for an arctangent calculator and type 1 .. you will get your answer

Comment: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/radians-to-degrees.htm

Comment: Evaluate tan ($\pi$/3)...It is not equal to 1

Comment: I will not except this answer until someone explain to me what is the connection or how to convert $\frac{-5}{-5}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Arctan_Calculator.htm .. type 1... As you want tan($\theta$)=1

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: You’re going to have much better results on this site if you stop being so combative and demanding things from people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You made an arithmetic mistake. Second equation should rearrange to y=2x+5/2.